# Trying to center a menu within a header?

Tags: css, html

[**Here's a jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/px4Qy/)

My goal is to have a menu with 95% width of the header centered.

Why doesn't the background color of the `#header` or the `#menu` show up?

When I do manage to have the background colors appear, it's not centered within the header.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<header id="header">    
      <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    background: black;
}
#menu {
    background: #bf4040;
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: auto;
}
    ul#nav li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        list-style-image: none;
        margin: 2px 2px;
    }
    ul#nav li a {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 37px;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0px 15px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    }
ul#nav li.current a, ul#nav li a:hover {
        color: #ffe200;
        background: #3d5a81;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because they have no height!
This is due to all the `float:` you are using, try replacing that with `display:inline-block` and you should be close to a solution.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/px4Qy/2/
```

I added `text-align:right;` to position the nav.
Change this to `text-align:center;` to center the menu.

Answer (score -1):

The `#menu` element isn't getting a background colour as it has no computed height since the nav items are floating, either set a fixed height on it or add `overflow: hidden`

```
#menu {
    background: #bf4040;
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden /* clears the floating elements giving the container height */
}
```

Comment: adding this comment after I realised I completely ignored the main question, the answer by @daniel will sort out the centering of the nav and also fix the background.